# Is it possible to get a list of node types (or even property types) in Alfresco?

Tags: lucene, extjs, alfresco

Is there a way that I can call alfresco via webscript and get back a list of node types or list of node properties that are available?  So if there are three different node types (cm:content, cm:folder, and cm:foo), I'd get that three returned to me (and not actually nodes that are one of these three types)?

Reason why I'm asking is that I would like to query the server for available search fields to be used in a database search.  If it helps, I'm using extjs library with Alfresco (opsoro), and using lucene search atm.  Any help into the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a webscript exists. You can find all the webscripts provided by alfresco looking at the url http://host/alfresco/service/index.

What you can do is implement the webscript yourself and then just access it normaly like you would any other webscript. More info on how to implement webscripts [here](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts).

Comment: Thanks for a reply.  I couldn't find a way to do this specific action, so I ended up changing my approach to the problem, which turned out for the better!  Again, thanks!

Comment: Just an update, I eventually found out that I could use the DictionaryService to get access to the ContentModel, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get Class Definitions` web script, it returns all the metadata related to the given content type. The url is as follows, just pass the name of the class you want, e.g. `cm_content`.

`http://your.host/alfresco/service/api/classes/{className}`

It will dump the metadata as JSON. I actually answered a very similar question, see [How to get list of aspects in the systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063503/how-to-get-list-of-aspects-in-the-systems/4617093#4617093)