# How to get list of aspects in the systems

Tags: java, web-services, alfresco

Does one can recommend me how to get list of aspects in alfresco using java web-service API.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get the list of aspects using web service client, you can however get the list of class definitions of aspects if you know their names.

Check `DictionaryServiceSoapPort` interface, there is a method named `getClasses` that can return an array of `ClassDefinition`s for the given types and aspects.

I don't know if it helps but instead of retrieving the list of aspects using web service, you can as well get the list of all types by calling `Get Class Definitions` web script. The url pattern is as follows.

`http://localhost:8086/alfresco/service/api/classes/{className}`

You can call the same web script without `className`, this time it will output all the classes in the dictionary as JSON, both the types and aspects (aspects are marked with "isAspect"=true).

Answer (score 1):

This may be late for you, but you can use the DictionaryService (in case somebody else searches for this:

[Alfresco Wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Dictionary_Web_Service) says:

> getClasses Get a list of type and
>   aspect definitions from the
>   dictionary.
>
> ClassDefinition[]
>   getClasses(ClassPredicate types,
>   ClassPredicate aspects)
>
> Parameters:
>
> types - the predicate for controlling
>   the types returned, or null to return
>   all types aspects - the predicate for
>   controlling the aspects returned, or
>   null to return all aspects Return:
>
> a list of class definitions that
>   relate to the requested types.